# Send Indside ul data by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How would you send ul->li data in a form by Ajax.  I want to send all the data in ul ->li by ajax and jquery.

```
  <form id="rightData" method="POST">
                        <ul class="list-group" id="accordian">

                            <!-- right list  -->

                        </ul>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
                    </form>
```

JS Pushing list from json in UL

```
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d6n2a', function (data) {
            data.topic_info.qt_ct_connection.map(value => {
                value.ct_list.forEach((CTLIST, index) => {

                    $tBody.append(`<li class="list-group-item" id="rl">${CTLIST.ct}
                    <p id=${index}class="show">

                            <a href="#demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
                                <div id="demo_${CTLIST.ct}" class="collapse">
                          <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[2]}</label> <input type="text" value="${CTLIST.tts}><br>
                          <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[1]}</label> <input type="text" value="${CTLIST.topic_level}"><br> 
                            <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[4]}</label> <input type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually && 'checked')}  > <br>

                          <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[3]}</label><input type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.check_for_geometry && 'checked')}  > <br>
                           </div>        
                    </p>
                    </li>`);



                });
```

how  can i use post method to send data un everly

in one click of submit

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect all the data with formData and append the ul items' values to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData